# Printing of nodes in linked-list with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am in the process of brushing up my C++ after 4-5 years and while going through this video (specific problem point screenshot attached), the speaker mentions that the code to **print a linked list** is actually doing a **call by value**.

But as far as my knowledge of pointers goes, isn't the `head` parameter in the `Print` function already a pointer to the address of `head` in the main function? In which case, the two variables should share the same memory location.

Could you please explain?

```
void Print(Node* head) {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    printf("List is: ");
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf(" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    Node* head = NULL; // empty list.
    printf("How many numbers?\n");
    int n, i, x;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the number" \n);
        scanf("%d", &x);
        Insert(x);
        Print(head);
    }
}
```

Comment: Call by value means you get a copy of the pointer.  It points to a value that you can change, but you can't change the pointer itself.

Comment: The code looks more like C. This doesn't seem like a good video for brushing up on C++.

Comment: @Mat sorry about that, been up 36 hours straight. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker is right.

```
void Print (Node *head) { ...
```

is passing a pointer to head (by value) to the `Print` function. Don't confuse the C++ use of references (e.g. `void Print (Node& head) {...` with the plain old C "pass a pointer" as is done in your code.

*Well is it pass by value or pass by reference?*

C++ retains a lot of C heritage. In C there is no pass by reference -- it's all pass by value. When you use the plain old "pass a pointer" with `Node *head`, you are simply passing a pointer "by-value". The `Print` function receives a *copy of* the pointer.

*What, a copy of the pointer?*

Yes, but recall, a pointer is simply a variable that holds the address to something else as it value. So even though `Print` gets a copy of `head` the value held by the copy is the exact same address that `head` has in the calling function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time explaining this! So essentially if I want this to be passed by reference the parameter in the calling function should be &head and the print function parameter changes to double pointer, ** head correct?

Comment: This way the actual address of the head node gets referenced and all changes reflected. So then, the code should function as expected?

Comment: Essentially yes, when you pass the *address of* a pointer (e.g. `Node **head`, and in the caller you have the `head` pointer, you are passing as `&head`, you are passing the *address of the pointer*) It is still passed by value, but instead of receiving a copy of a pointer to `head`, the function now receives a copy of a pointer containing the *address of the pointer to head* as opposed to the *address of head*. That allows you to change the address of `head` within the function. (which is why you pass `Node **` to `insert(..)` and simply `Node*` to `Print()`.

Comment: It all has to do with what changes will be visible in the calling function. If you pass `Node *`, the function gets a copy of the pointer, and any changes made to the copy (e.g. `head = newhead;` will not be seen back in the caller (because you assigned the new address to a copy). However, when you pass `&head` using `Node **`, you now have the actual pointer to head (e.g. a copy containing the address of the pointer to head), so now `*head = newhead;` will change the address held by the pointer to head and the change will be visible in the caller.

Comment: So to summarize, if you are calling a function that can change the address of `head` (the starting address for your list), you have to pass the address of head to the function, (e.g. pass `&head` using a `Node**` parameter). Otherwise, if the list address isn't changed (e.g. `head` isn't changed), you can simply pass `head` via `Node*` and then happily iterate over your list, insert or delete nodes (**other than head**), etc.. because nothing you are doing is changing the starting address for your list (e.g. the address held by `head`)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation David. You are a star!

Comment: I'm just glad you got it. Once you get this straight in your mind -- a lot of the mystery of why pointers are passed the way they are goes away. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

The `node*` is specifying that you want the pointer, and not a full copy of the nodes data to be passed in